# how can I read a YAML file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have such a YAML file:

```
Company1:
  name: Something1
  established: 2000
#
Company2:
  name: Something2
  established: 1932
```

reading the YAML file: (** UPDATE **)

```
    config = YAML.load_file('file.yaml')
    config.each do |key, value|
     if(key == 'name')
      company_name = value
      #year = config['Company1']['established']
      year = config.fetch(key)['established']
     end
   end
```

** UPDATE **
Now the above code is working, but it shows the result as:

```
 company1 =>  {"name" => "something1"} => {"established year" => 2000"}
```

how can I remove the the {} and "" ?

Comment: I wrote up a detailed answer, but saw Mori's answer come in.  That answer is probably all you need to know.  Because of the lack of indenting in your displayed YAML file, you were just reassigning the key (which needs to be unique) in the same Hash, and so you were seeing this behavior.

Comment: I appreciate if you could help me with a code snippet, I still have the problem.

Comment: With what you have learned so far, from the answers given, you can show your edits and that will help us help you by seeing where you are going wrong.

Comment: You aren't getting that error with your current code in your question.   Your if statement is not being triggered.  And now your question is migrating toward "How do I use a nested Hash?"  Might consider having this asked in http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: just update my code, please have a check.

Comment: You would just ask for the 'name' just like you do for any other hash.  `puts "#{config['Company1']['name']} was established in #{config['Company1']['established']}"`

Answer (score 42):

Okay, so this is your YAML file right?

```
Company1:
  name: Something1
  established: 2000

Company2:
  name: Something2
  established: 1932
```

Okay now this YAML file actually represents a Hash. The has has two keys i.e Company1, Company2 (because they are the leading entries and the sub entries (name and established) are indented under them). The value of these two keys is again a Hash. This Hash also has 2 keys namely name and established. And they have values like Something1 and 2000 respectively etc.

So when you do,

```
config=YAML.load_file('file.yml')
```

And print config (which is a Hash representing the YAML file contents) using,

```
puts config
```

you get following output:

```
{"Company1"=>{"name"=>"Something1", "established"=>2000}, "Company2"=>{"name"=>"Something2", "established"=>1932}}
```

So we have a Hash object as described by the YAML file.

Using this Hash is pretty straight forward.

Since each company's name and year come in a separate hash held by the outer hash (company1, company2), we can iterate through the companies. The following Code prints the Hash.

```
config.each do |company,details|
  puts company
  puts "-------"
  puts "Name: " + details["name"]
  puts "Established: " + details["established"].to_s
  puts "\n\n"
end
```

So in Each iteration we get access to each (key,value) of the Hash. This in first iteration we have `company`(key) as `Company1` and `details`(value) as `{"name"=>"Something1", "established"=>2000}`

Hope this helped.

Comment: LOL, this was pretty close to the first answer I started, from reading the question as it was originally, and saw the first answer.  So I thought about it and cancelled my answer, as it was just too much information given.  Now after the back and forth and finding out that indeed the question asked just the full bowl of doubts.  This answer is now appropriate.  So you get an upvote from me.  And hopefully accepted answer.  The question should be :How do I read from YAML and how do I use the resulting nested Hash:

Comment: This was super helpful!

Answer (score 4):

[YAML uses indentation for scoping](http://yaml.org/spec/current.html#id2519916), so try, e.g.:

```
Company1:
  name: Something1
  established: 2000

Company2:
  name: Something2
  established: 1932
```

Comment: Then can I get the established year using this `year = config.fetch('established')` ?

Comment: I guess you should go for config['Company1']['established'] as Company1 and Company2 are just keys in a hash.

Comment: but this ends up with `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: In the console you can find the right format by using `to_yaml`, e.g. `> {foo: :bar, baz: :qux}.to_yaml`.

Comment: sorry couldn't get it, above give me something like this: `---
:foo: :bar
:baz: :qux`. Sorry for stupid question, I am new in ruby.